# multiply each group by a specific value from a list in python groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following data frame and a list.

```
d = ({
    'Item' : ['a','a','a','b','b','b','b'],                 
    'Count' : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6],                                      
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

list_factor=[10,100] # a list of factors with same length as the unique Items in dataframe.
```

Now I would like for each item, multiply the count by list_factor element correspond to that item. For example all counts in a will be multiplied by 10 and all counts in b will be multiplied by 100. So the final data frame will looks like this:

```
'Item' : ['a','a','a','b','b','b','b'],                 
'Count' : [0,10,20,300,400,500,600],
```

I tried to use groupby function and apply a multiplication function to it, but I can do it only for a constant value, not a value from the list. Here is what I did:

```
df.groupby('Item')['Count'].apply(lambda x : x*list_factor[?!])
```

This is just an example data frame and what I want to reach. In reality I have a data frame with 1000 different Items and as a result a list_factor with length of 1000. (The data frame has total rows of 40000)

Comment: Based on which logic, exactly? what if the number of unique values in `Item` and the length of `list_factor` do not match?

Comment: They do match. This is my specific question. Assume that you have for each item one specific factor in the list of factors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `factorize` to extract the order of `Item`, then numpy indexing to propagate the factor:

```
factors = np.array(list_factor)[df.Item.factorize()[0]]

df['Count'] *= factors
```

Output:

```
  Item  Count
0    a      0
1    a     10
2    a     20
3    b    300
4    b    400
5    b    500
6    b    600
```

Answer (score 2):

Quang Hoang's answer is interesting- I wasn't familiar with factorize.
Another approach would be to create a dictionary:

```
item_values = df['Item'].unique()
factor_dict = {item_values[i]: list_factor[i] for i in range(len(item_values))}


df['Count'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Count'] * factor_dict.get(x['Item']), axis=1)
```

Result:

```
  Item  Count
0    a      0
1    a     10
2    a     20
3    b    300
4    b    400
5    b    500
6    b    600
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is a very interesting way of doing it using dictionaries. I accepted Quang answer as it was way faster for a large data frame that I had. Thanks :)